# Which graph or chart to use for conversion

Tags: charts, help, graphs

Which chart or graph should I use to represent this data?

- # of emails sent (100)
- # of responses to emails (30)
- Of those responses (30), the # of people who took action (10)

I am being asked to show the conversion rates.

Comment: To clarify, you’re saying that 100 emails were sent, 30 were opened, and 10 took action by clicking a link in the email?

Comment: Numerous charts would show this information, you could also just write it, not really a UX question.

Comment: @MichaelHogan not quite - I am saying 100 emails were sent, 30 people actually took action from that email (clicked on a link and posted a job) and 10 of those 30 people were actually hired. Sorry for being confusing! I need to show a visual of this,

Answer (score 1):

You could show something similar to how HotJar does it:

The line progression clearly shows drop-off, while it tells both % and amount. Furthermore, it also shows how many made it to the next stage and the %.

Your chart numbers would be something like this:

**100** | **30** (30% of 100) (70% of 100 drop-off) | **10** (33% of 30) (67% of 30 drop-off)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show this information as a stacked chart. As you have more and more campaigns you will want to compare them.  At that point you may want to compare them and you may be more interested in conversion / action rate based on percentage. Placing them side by side will allow easy comparison.

Ultimately you will have many different types of displays. For instance you may want to drill-down into a campaign and see response rate over time; then you may want to compare campaigns over time as well.

[image]